# Extended access tokens & users on public terminals

Tags: facebook-graph-api, offline, access-token

I have a few issues with the new extended access tokens that have replaced the offline_access permission...

1. If a user grants you an extended access token while using a public computer, & then subsequently logs out from that computer, from what I can gather, the acces token that should work for 60 days, stops working
2. If, using an extended access token, you request page access tokens (using /me/accounts), select & save the token for the page you wish to use... then, later on, would like to get an access token for a different page for the same user, requesting the new access tokens (using /me/accounts) seems to invalidate the one you previously saved, meaning that any time you want to add the ability to interact as a different page, you have to update all the previously stored access tokens

I was wondering if anyone has found a way around these?

Am I missing something here, or does this new solution seem completely un-usable?

Answer (score 0):

ad 1.) - No, that’s not true. Just logging out of Facebook does not invalidate long-lived access tokens.

ad 2.) - I can’t reproduce that testing it with Graph API Explorer and Debug Tool. I get a page access token for one of my sites, then I log out of FB and back in again. That gives me a different user access token in the Graph API Explorer, and also the page access token displayed for that same site as before is a different one. Nevertheless, the Debug Tool still shows that the page access token that I got before is still valid for about 2 months.